# HttpClient GetAsync always says 'WaitingForActivation'

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am new to HttpClient. My code below always says "WaitingForActivation" in the status. Please help

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeCall()
{
    var httpclient = new HttpClient();

    var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("http://localhost:60565/Subscribers");

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, if you environment is Synchronous add `.Result`, like so:

```
GetAsync("http://localhost:60565/Subscribers").Result;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's normal. Just `await` the returned task to (asynchronously) wait for it to complete.

You may find my [intro to `async`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Cleary wrote in his post, in order to create an asynchronous call your task should be awaited too. That means, the method in your question (`MakeCall()`) is asynchronous but probably the call to the method is synchronous.

An asynchronous example class:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class SampleClass
{
  public async Task<string> MakeCall()
  {
    # I am using the asynchronous call from the HttpClient library
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, creds)
    ...
  }
}
```

Try to await the call to the method.

```
var makeCall = await SampleClass.MakeCall();
```

What I would avoid is using `.Result`. As JDandChips already implies, it makes your call again synchronous. In this case, however, there is no need to try to make is asynchronous in the first place.

Comment: `The name 'await' does not exists in the current context` That is what I get when I try this. Also, what should `class` be in this example ?

Comment: @GuidoG , I added a sample class. As I said, I use `.PostAsJsonAsync()` for an API call.

Comment: Thanks for the sample